# NoReverseMatch проблема с построением пути/передачи аргументов?

Tags: python, django

**Models.py:**

```python
class Debtor(models.Model):
    ...
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Url', unique=True,) 
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.short_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('debtor-detail', kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
        
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.short_name)
        super(Debtor, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**Views.py:**

```python
class Debtor_List(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    login_url = 'signin'
    template_name = 'main/debtor_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'debtor_list'
    paginate_by = 1
    allow_empty = True

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = 'Должники'
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Debtor.objects.filter(user__id=self.request.user.id)


class Debtor_Create(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    login_url = 'signin'
    form_class = DebtorCreateForm
    template_name = 'main/debtor_create.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy ('debtor-list')

   def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(Debtor_Create, self).form_valid(form)

class Debtor_Detail(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    login_url = 'signin'
    model = Debtor 
    template_name = 'main/debtor_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'debtor_detail'


class Debtor_Update(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    login_url = 'signin'
    model = Debtor
context_object_name = 'debtor_update'
    form_class = DebtorUpdateForm
    template_name = 'main/debtor_update.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy ('debtor-detail')
```

**Urls.py:**

```python
urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name='home'),
    path('debtor/', Debtor_List.as_view(), name='debtor-list'),
    path('debtor/create/', Debtor_Create.as_view(), name='debtor-create'),
    path('debtor/<str:slug>/', Debtor_Detail.as_view(), name='debtor-detail'),
    path('debtor/<str:slug>/update/', Debtor_Update.as_view(), name='debtor-update'),
  ]
```

Программа отрабатывает отображение списка должников **Debtor_List** с ссылками, создает новых должников **Debtor_Create**, просматривает инфо по отдельно-взятому должнику **Debtor_Detail** с построением корректной ссылки по слагу - `debtor/<str:slug>/`. Но если я добавляю в шаблон для просмотра Debtor_Detail кнопки (ссылки) на форму редактирования  `{% url 'debtor-update' %}`, то в конечном итоге все ломается ... при нажатии на должнике выдает ошибку:

```
NoReverseMatch at /debtor/dp-ddsmts/
Reverse for '<b>debtor-update</b>' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['debtor/(?P<slug>[^/]+)/update/$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/debtor/dp-ddsmts/
Django Version: 3.2.4
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'debtor-update' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['debtor/(?P<slug>[^/]+)/update/$']
Exception Location: D:\Dev\z-Projects\SEDAK\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py, line 694, in _reverse_with_prefix
Python Executable:  D:\Dev\z-Projects\SEDAK\venv\scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.5
Python Path:    
['D:\\Dev\\z-Projects\\SEDAK\\sedak',
 'C:\\Python395\\python39.zip',
 'C:\\Python395\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python395\\lib',
 'C:\\Python395',
 'D:\\Dev\\z-Projects\\SEDAK\\venv',
 'D:\\Dev\\z-Projects\\SEDAK\\venv\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 30 Jun 2021 11:11:22 +0000
```

Как я понимаю, по именованной ссылке `name='debtor-update'` не передается параметр **slug** в связи с чем Django не может построить корректно ссылку `'debtor/<str:slug>/update/'`.
Что нужно сделать, чтобы UpdateView передавало аргумент slug для построения маршрута??? и чтобы Django корректно отрабатывала по именованным ссылкам:

```python
path('debtor/<str:slug>/', Debtor_Detail.as_view(), name='debtor-detail'),
path('debtor/<str:slug>/update/', Debtor_Update.as_view(), name='debtor-update'),
```

***Примечание***:

> если в шаблоне в ссылке передать slug `{% url 'debtor-update' debtor_detail.slug %}` то будет все работать. Но корректно ли из
> шаблона передавать slug? и как сделать чтобы сама вьюха
> `Debtor_Update(..., UpdateView)` передавала параметр slug для
> построения пути в urls?

**Шаблон для представления Devtor_Detail**:

```html
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
    {% load static %}
    
    {% block title %}{{ block.super }} :: {{ debtor_detail.short_name }}{% endblock %}
    {% block main_content %}
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h5>Информация про 
                    <span style="color: #7267EF">{{ debtor_detail.short_name }}</span>
                </h5>
            </div>
            
            <div class="card-body">
                <form action="" class="mt-4">
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <div class="row mb-2 align-items-center">
                            <label for="" class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Идентификационный код:</label>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <span class="form-control bg-light">{{ debtor_detail.kod }}</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row mb-2 align-items-center">
                            <label for="" class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Номер дела о банкрутстве:</label>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <span class="form-control bg-light">{{ debtor_detail.case_num }}</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row mb-2 align-items-center">
                            <label for="" class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Номенклатурный номер:</label>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <span class="form-control bg-light">{{ debtor_detail.nomenclature_num }}</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
    
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6 mt-4">
                        <label for="" class="form-label">Наименование:</label>
                        <span class="form-control bg-light">{{ debtor_detail.full_name }}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6 mt-4">
                        <label for="" class="form-label">Сокращенное наименование:</label>
                        <span class="form-control bg-light">{{ debtor_detail.short_name }}</span>
                    </div>
    
                    <div class="form-group mt-4">
                        <label class="form-label">Местонахождение:</label>
                    </div>
    
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <div class="form-group mb-2">
                                <label for="" class="form-label"><em>Страна:</em></label>
                                <span class="form-control form-control-sm bg-light">{{ debtor_detail.add_country }}</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group mb-2">
                                <label for="" class="form-label"><em>Индекс:</em></label>
                                <span class="form-control form-control-sm bg-light">{{ debtor_detail.add_index }}</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group mb-2">
                                <label for="" class="form-label"><em>Область:</em></label>
                                <span class="form-control form-control-sm bg-light">{{ debtor_detail.add_region }}</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group mb-2">
                                <label for="" class="form-label"><em>Район:</em></label>
                                <span class="form-control form-control-sm bg-light">{{ debtor_detail.add_district }}</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group mb-2">
                                <label for="" class="form-label"><em>{{ debtor_detail.add_city_type }}:</em></label>
                                <span class="form-control form-control-sm bg-light">{{ debtor_detail.add_city }}</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
    
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <div class="form-group mb-2">
                                <label for="" class="form-label"><em>{{ debtor_detail.add_street_type }}:</em></label>
                                <span class="form-control form-control-sm bg-light">{{ debtor_detail.add_street }}</span>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="form-group mb-2">
                                <label for="" class="form-label"><em>дом:</em></label>
                                <span class="form-control form-control-sm bg-light w-25">{{ debtor_detail.add_building }}</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group mb-2">
                                <label for="" class="form-label"><em>корпус:</em></label>
                                <span class="form-control form-control-sm bg-light w-25">{{ debtor_detail.add_corps }}</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group mb-2">
                                <label for="" class="form-label"><em>офис:</em></label>
                                <span class="form-control form-control-sm bg-light w-25">{{ debtor_detail.add_office }}</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
    
    
                    <div class="row gy-2 gx-3 align-items-center mt-3">
                        <div class="col-auto">
                            <span class="form-label">Дата создания:</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-auto">
                            <span class="form-label text-primary">{{ debtor_detail.create_time|date:"d.m.Y H:i:s" }}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-auto">
                            <span class="form-label">Дата внесения изменений:</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-auto">
                            <span class="form-label text-primary">{{ debtor_detail.update_time|date:"d.m.Y H:i:s" }}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
    
                <a class="btn btn-primary mt-4" href="{% url 'debtor-update' %}" role="button">
                    <i class="mr-2" data-feather="edit"></i>
                    Редактировать запись
                </a>
            
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Ну не знаю. Можно воспользоваться методом get_context_data и через kwargs получить нужные url-параметры или методом form_valid, в нём из формы получить slug (через cleaned_data)

Answer (score 0):

Вариант первый

у вас тип `str` для `slug`. Вроде должен быть `slug:slug`. И  на сколько помню, `slug` тип не может содержать `/` и тогда текущий вариант урлов должен пройти исправно.

Второй вариант,  если вариант выше не подходит по какой либо причине -

```
path('debtor/<str:slug>/', Debtor_Detail.as_view(), name='debtor-detail'),
path('debtor/<str:slug>/update/', Debtor_Update.as_view(), name='debtor-update'),
```

Поменяйте местами  или

Третий вариант - замените на

```
path('debtor/<str:slug>/', include([
    path('', Debtor_Detail.as_view(), name='debtor-detail'),
    path('update/', Debtor_Update.as_view(), name='debtor-update'),
])
```

Это связано с особенностями поиска url в django.

Comment: 1й , 2й и 3й варианты, как и ранее, работают только если из шаблона Debtor_detail передавать через именованную ссылку  параметр slug `href="{% url 'debtor-update'  debtor_detail.slug %}"`.
Замена `<str:slug>` на `<slug:slug>` не приводит к каким-либо изменениям работы программы, как и замена местами путей или использование include в путях

Comment: а как вы хотиту указать django в ссылке для какого объекта показывать страницу обновления/детальную страницу? передача аргумента обязательна (если вы не передаете аргумент иным образом)

Comment: если бы указали в вопросе html шаблон, то я б и про это написал. а сейчас получается спрашиваете одно, а хотите другое

Comment: я ведь в шаблоне указываю именованную ссылку **debtor-update**, что привязана к **Debtor_Update.as_view()**, но не получается иным способом получить слаг в данном представлении и передать для построения пути. Возможно вопрос звучит не совсем внятно!? постараюсь сформулировать его более корректно

Comment: почему не получается, в чем проблема? приведите html шаблон

Comment: в шаблоне для представления Debtor_Detail есть кнопка **редактировать запись** и если там указать именованную ссылку на представление Debtor_Update (бед дополнительного указания параметра слаг), то Джанго выдает ошибку, что для **debtor-update** `Reverse for 'debtor-update' with no arguments not found`. А вот как сделать так, чтобы аргумент слаг брался (иным способом) из самого представления Debtor_Update и передавался для построения пути по именованной ссылке из данного представления - не понятно )))

Comment: или тут вся загвоздка в том, что Debtor_Update.as_view() не понимает с каким объектом модели ему работать ...